# How to send same cookies (CookieJar) in http.Client for different domains

Tags: go, networking, cookies, httpcookie

I'm using `http.Client` for making HTTP requests for some production resource.

> This resource has two different domains with the same business-logic
> (for example: example.com, instance.com). So ALL cookies for example.com is valid for instance.com and so.

The problem is that I need to send same cookies to two different domains, that is not possible in GoLang.

`func (*Jar) Cookies` returns cookies for url with a specific domain, so I must call some cookies-preparation function:

```
func (session *Session) PrepareCookiesForExample() {
    example, _ := url.Parse("https://example.com")

    session.client.Jar.SetCookies(example, session.client.Jar.Cookies(commu))
}
```

So I have to call this function in my each request that is pretty uncomfortable and can cause errors (because cookies are not sent) if I forget to call this fuction.

> How to send the same cookies for ALL domains by using CookieJar?

Comment: `http.CookieJar` is an interface, so you can write whatever implementation you want. If you want to send the same cookies everywhere, you could do this by writing your own CookieJar implementation, or perhaps by wrapping the existing one to modify behavior.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I'm new to GoLang.

Could you advise how can I create custom implementation of the method `Cookies(u *url.URL) []*Cookie` ?

Comment: net/http/cookiejar doesn’t allow what you want to do. Immerhin lmplement your own Jar. SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: So what should I do? How to fix my problem?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a reminder that restricting cookies to the domains they were set from is an important security feature that should not be bypassed lightly.
Here is an example of how you'd create your own cookie Jar:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
)

type SharedCookieJar struct {
    CookieSlice []*http.Cookie
}

func (jar *SharedCookieJar) SetCookies(u *url.URL, cookies []*http.Cookie) {
    jar.CookieSlice = append(jar.CookieSlice, cookies...)
}

func (jar *SharedCookieJar) Cookies(u *url.URL) []*http.Cookie {
    return jar.CookieSlice
}
    
func main() {
    c := http.Client{
        Jar:&SharedCookieJar{},
    }

    c.Get("https://example.com/")
    c.Get("https://instance.com/") // will use cookies set by example.com
}
```

Further reading on interfaces here: https://tour.golang.org/methods/9